# FindWindow and SetParent - causes the child window (or process) to exit

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I had tried to obtain IntPtr to a child process's window using FindWindow(string className, string windowName), and then call SetParent(Intptr childWindow, IntPtr parentWindow) to set the child process window into the parent window.

Somehow, the child process's window was not set into the parent, and the child process exits after SetParent() was executed.

Child process is ran outside of code (double-clicking on the exe file)

Following is the snippet of code in the parent program:

```
public void Hops()
{
    IntPtr ptr = FindWindow(null, "WinAp");

    // this is a WPF window
    var currentWindowHelper = WindowInteropHelper(this);  
    SetWindow(ptr, currentWindowHelper.Handle);
}
```

However, if I start the child process within the Hops() function programmatically (using Process)   instead of using FindWindow(), there is no issue with using SetParent() - ie. Child window is set into the Parent window.

So, the question is, why does the child process exit?  The IntPtr value returned by FindWindow() seems like a correct value...

Comment: A program that opens a top-level window and then suddenly finds that some other program has tried to transform that window into a child window can misbehave in all kinds of ways. [Related reading](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/15/9978691.aspx)

Comment: You didn't perform any error checking. In any case, cross-process parenting is something that we did back in 16 bit Windows. You aren't supposed to do it any more. Find a different way to solve whatever problem you are facing.